# How to purge Teamcity's nuget feed?

Tags: nuget, teamcity

Due to some mistakes I made in configuring some builds my Teamcity nuget feed has the wrong artefacts in some of the feeds. How do I purge the feeds so I can restart them from scratch?

Answer (score 3):

Buried in the **Using Team City as a NuGet Server** section at this [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/NuGet#NuGet-UsingTeamCityasNuGetServer), you'll find the following text:

"If the build artifacts are changed under TeamCity Data Directory manually, you need to instruct TeamCity to reindex NuGet feed. For that, click "reset" link for "buildsMetadata" under Administration > Diagnostic > Caches."

Answer (score -1):

you can use nuget command line:

**list**

```
nuget locals all -list
```

**clear**

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

you can even run it as build step...